# Error 404 load images althought still working

Tags: http-status-code-404, fetch-api

I am working on a movie app project for my portfolio, and I am fetching data from the TMDB API. Everything seems fine, but I am getting this error on my console.log `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/originalundefined 404`. Why is this error happening, and how should I fix it?

I am quite confused about how UseEffect works. Although I have `setCurrentMovie(request.data)` in my Effect, I still cannot access the `currentMovie` state in the `return` code. The error on the log looks like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'poster_path')` with every props of `currentMovie`. My temporary solution is to put a "?" after each `currentMovie` (because someone in some a tutorial did that) props that I want to access (and it works), but I don't really understand it. If you understand what I am saying, please provide me with any documentation to help me understand this issue more clearly.

Here my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "../api/axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react'


function MovieDetail() {
    const [currentMovie, setCurrenttMovie] = useState();
    const { types , id } = useParams();
    const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel({slidesToScroll: 'auto'})
    
    useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0,0)
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchMovie = async () => {
        const request = await axios.get(`/${types}/${id}?api_key=da18bcc962a30b615ed38969455bbbcb&append_to_response=credits,videos&language=en-US`);
        setCurrenttMovie(request.data);
      }
      fetchMovie();
    },[])

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <div className=" bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover w-full h-[650px] lg:h-screen" 
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${currentMovie?.backdrop_path}')`, boxShadow: '50px -50px 200px 50px black inset' }}>
        </div>  
        
        <div className=" absolute flex flex-col top-[150px] items-center z-10 lg:flex-row lg:items-start max-w-7xl gap-2 px-2 lg:px-8">
            <div className="shadow-inner w-[315px] shrink-0">
              <img src={`https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w342${currentMovie?.poster_path}`} alt={currentMovie?.title} className="w-[315px] h-[440px] rounded-lg shadow-2xl" />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col px-4 gap-4 overflow-hidden">
                    <h1 className="font-bold">{currentMovie?.title  || currentMovie?.name}</h1>
                    <p className="text-white lg:text-xl">{currentMovie?.overview}</p>
                    <div ref={emblaRef} className="overflow-hidden hidden xl:block"> 
                      <div className="flex">
                        {currentMovie?.credits.cast.map(cast => {
                          return (
                            <div key={cast.cast_id} className="shrink-0 grow-0 basis-1/5 min-w-0">
                              <img src={`https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_face${cast.profile_path}`} alt="" className="w-[160px] h-[190px]"/>
                            </div>
                          )
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default MovieDetail
```